# How to change colour of the certain words in label - Swift 3

Tags: swift, colors, label, swift3, nsmutableattributedstring

Created a Label with a simple text.

How can I change the color of the certain words in the label?

Swift 3

Like below-

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Too broad. You haven't given any code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString` to apply colors for different words in a string.
Try this, there are already lot of similar questions have the answers in SO.

```
let myLabel = UILabel()
var stringOne = "Swift 3 has come"
let stringTwo = "has"

let range = (stringOne as NSString).range(of: stringTwo)

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: stringOne)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue , range: range)
myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: Thanks, good decision! But this way we can change the color only of the one word in our text. Do you know how to make it to all the words "has" in our text?

Comment: What do you mean `good decision`? You can use this idea to apply to other strings as well.

Comment: I mean if we have the string |
var stringOne = "Swift 3 has come, has has has come";
let stringTwo = "has" | 
It will color only first "has" in the stringOne. But how we can color
all 4 words "has" in our string? Thank You

Comment: Write a regular expression!

Comment: thanks it helped me in my case and i hv given upvote @Santosh